# Convert a date string with time zone to only weekday and date

Tags: java, date, timestamp, date-formatting

I'm having a string like this: `Wed Feb 20 02:48:00 GMT+05:30 2019`
and I need to convert it to `Wed 20`.

How can I do this?

I tried `string.replace()`, but that doesn't help
I'm a newbie please help

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed Feb 20 02:48:00 GMT+05:30 2019", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d", Locale.ENGLISH))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
class Test
{
        public static void main(String ... args)
        {
                String s="Wed Feb 20 02:48:00 GMT+05:30 2019";
                String arr[]=s.split(" ");
                if (arr.length >=3)
                {
                        String result=arr[0]+" "+arr[2];
                        System.out.println(result);
                }
        }
}
$ java Test
Wed 20
```

Comment: you can get Feb if you change this line
String result=arr[0]+" "+arr[1]+" "+arr[2];

Comment: thanks this was the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

If you will be working with dates that are always represented in this `String` format,
 then perhaps you can use the `String` [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, to break apart your date on the spaces.

```
String sourceDate = "Wed Feb 20 02:48:00 GMT+05:30 2019";
String[] dateParts = sourceDate.split(" ");
```

This will result in an `Array` containing the seperate blocks.

> dateParts = { 'Wed', 'Feb', '20','02:48:00', 'GMT+05:30', '2019' }

Then you can take the blocks you need

```
String resultDate = dateParts[0] +" "+ dateParts[2];
```

> Wed 20

---

If you intend to do other manipulations on the date, you might want to look into converting your date `String` to an actual `Date` using a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

This works like this:

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
System.out.println(date); // 2010-01-02
```

Where `LocalDate.parse()` needs to be replaced depending on your date format.
Only the date -> [`LocalDate#parse(text, formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)
Date and time -> [`LocalDateTime#parse(text, formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)
Date, time and timezone -> [`ZonedDateTime#parse(text, formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)

Comment: Even for a simple manipulation like this I would prefer to use the built-in date and time types as in your second example. It’s more high-level, tells the reader more clearly what is going on and why. And as you said, is future-proof in case one day we need for example `February` or `febrero` (in Spanish) or `02` instead of `Feb`.